# What is the .results property attached to a .json() call?

Tags: javascript, json, promise, es6-promise

So I'm not new to JavaScript but I'm trying to learn Angular2 and more about JavaScript ES6 Promises, and I'm working through [this tutorial](https://onsen.io/blog/tutorial-how-to-create-pokemon-app-using-angular2-cli/) to do so. In the section on building the `pokedex-service.ts` file, part of the `getPokemon()` function looks like this:

```
getPokemon(offset: number, limit: number) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}?offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().results) //<- line in question
      .then(
           // ... etc ...
      );
}
```

I understand that with Angular's HTTP service, it returns an Observable that is then converted to a Promise (via `toPromise()`), but I'm confused what happens on the next line: 
`.then (response => response.json().results)`.

Specifically, I get that `response` is a placeholder for the Promise passed into then, and I understand that `response.json()` converts the results of that Promise into a JSON object. But I can't figure out what the `.results` property is that's chained onto the end of `response.json()`.

I've checked [the Body.json() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) and, thinking perhaps it was a property of Promises, I checked [the Promises API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but can't find any properties (OR methods) in either API that correspond to `results`. What is this property, and where does it come from?

Additionally, how does it differ from simply using `response.json()` and what is its return value that gets passed into the next `then()`?

Comment: If I had to guess (and I do), I'd say it was the resolved results of the promise returned  by `.json()`.

Comment: Looks to me like someone is accessing the internals of the promise, which he shouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

When you request the server, the response will be a string. The .json() function is here to say "*I will convert your string response into a Javascript object*". That's the json() job. Then, once you have your object, you access to his property. Here, the server returns an object with a property results.

```
getPokemon(offset: number, limit: number) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}?offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().results) //<- line in question
      .then(
           (data) => { // your code }
      );
}
```

**data** will contain the content of "results" property

You should use operator map from "Rxjs" library, like this:

```
return return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}?offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .toPromise();
```

which is more generic. With this code, even if the server doesn't return an object with "results" property, it will work.

and the imports

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```